# Is it wrong to use files without extensions on a page?

Tags: html, minify

Why is it wrong to remove file extensions from files and html code, like this:

```
<link href="cs" rel="stylesheet">    
<script src="j"></script>
<img src="1">
```

Why does nobody do that? Will this cause any browser compatibility issues or penalties from search engines?

Comment: There will be penalty from developer who takes this project over from you.

Answer (score 2):

Well, for one, you'd better make sure all your filenames are unique, as your code can't tell the difference between `main.css` and `main.js`...

Comment: +1, this is exactly why an extension is important. Leaving out such vital information such as the file extension makes your code less reusable and assumes other developers that may be working on your code know what you're referring to, which is bad.

Answer (score 2):

The `src` and `href` attributes (among with virtually everything else on the web) uses *URLs*, not "files". URLs don't have file extensions. It's just a convention that `.XXX` is used in a URL, but it has no inherent meaning. As such, using meaningless one-letter URLs works just fine, yes. But there's no inherent advantage to it either, it just makes your source code and URLs less readable, even for yourself.

Comment: But there's still a way around it - to write comments near URLs. Then, strip the comments automatically with php. Anyway this isn't very productive, I know.